# Split a function's processing and response without a switch (looking for an alternative)

Tags: php, laravel, optimization

I have a function that processes the request and another function to returns a specific response. There has to be a better way/best practice for dealing with this, however I'm unsure.

```php
        $isResponseForm = $this->getIsResponseForm();
        $formResponse = null;

        switch ($this->formId) {
            case 'start':
                $formResponse = $isResponseForm ? $this->start() : $this->_start();
                $this->formId = $this->session->get('checkout_item.registration.has_penalty') ? 'late' : 'start';
                break;
            case 'late':
                $formResponse = $isResponseForm ? $this->late() : $this->_late();
                $this->formId = 'start';
                break;
            case 'search':
                $formResponse = $isResponseForm ? $this->search() : $this->_search();
                $this->formId = $this->session->exists('change.address') ? 'verify' : 'review';
                break;
            case 'verify':
                $formResponse = $isResponseForm ? $this->verify() : $this->_verify();
                $this->formId = 'address';
                break;
            case 'address':
                $formResponse = $isResponseForm ? $this->address() : $this->_address();
                $this->formId = 'review';
                break;
            case 'review':
                $formResponse = $isResponseForm ? $this->review() : $this->_review();
                break;
            case 'confirmation':
                $formResponse = $isResponseForm ? $this->confirmation() : null;
                break;
            default:
                $this->processor->errorLog->add('Invalid FormID: ' . $this->formId);
                $this->form->addError('An unknown error occurred (' . $this->processor->errorLog->getLastId() . ')');
        }

        if (!$isResponseForm) {
            $this->setIsResponseForm(true);
            return $this->processForm(); // restart the switch statement
        }

        return $formResponse;
```

`$isResponseForm` is set to true after the first iteration.
functions prefixed with an underscore `_` are for processing, and those without handle the response.

```
protected function start(): Form
    {
        $checkoutItem = $this->session->get('checkout_item');

        $options = (new Collection($checkoutItem['options']))->sortBy('value');

        $this->form->setFormId('search');
        $this->form->header(
            'FIGURE LENGTH',
            'FigLengthHeaderSlug'
        );
        $this->form->checkbox(
            'Change my Address',
            'address_change'
        );

        return $this->form;
    }
```

Ex:

- Step 1: `$this->_start();`
- Step 2: `return $this->start();`

I had them in the same function, but it was messy and I decided to split them up.

Comment: I don’t see much wrong with this (apart from your method naming conventions maybe …) Sure you could do this in other ways, but they’re probably not going to be any shorter and/or easier to read and maintain either.

Comment: Can we see the whole class?

Comment: I added one of the form response functions, the other `_start()` function doesn't return anything and really just modifies the session. It's just not very feasible to show each of the classes just because there is a lot more going on than what I'm currently facing.